# Creating responsive grid with FlexBox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having a real complicated situation that I'm trying to resolve.
I try to create a 2 columns (maximum) layout on bigger displays and 1 column on small display (Smaller than 450px).

I have no simple way to explain so here some images:

- 2-Columns Layout (Notice that **every row cells should be in the same height**)

[image: 2 Columns Layout]

- Expected 1-Column Layout (Notice that **'B' cells should come after all 'A' cells)**

[image: 1 Column Layout]

I manage to accomplish the 2-columns display with the following css.

```
.breeding-row {
       /* equal height of the children */
           display: flex;
  }

  .breeding-col {
         /* additionally, equal width */
        flex: 1;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
           .breeding-col {
                  flex-basis: 100%;
            }
           .breeding-row {
               flex-direction: column;
             }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 450px) {
        .breeding-col {
                flex-basis: 50%;
          }
     }
```

This works great for 2 columns. But when it becomes 1 column the cells, obviously, positioned one after another and I get...

- Actual result for 1 column

[image]

I'm trying to think of something that will work for both 1 and 2 columns display and will give me the 1 column expected result... 
I will highly appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `order` property to change their order on smaller screens.

In combination with a media query you can do like this, where you make the even children (2 and 4) get `order: 1` (the default is `0`) when screen goes below 600px, and together with changing the flex direction to `column` and they will stack on top of each other.

As the default value of `align-items` is `stretch`, the items will have the same height per row.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex div {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.flex div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .flex {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .flex div {
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
  .flex div:nth-child(even) {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>R1<br>R1<br>R1<br>R1<br>R1<br></div>
  <div>B1</div>
  <div>R2</div>
  <div>B2<br>B2<br>B2<br></div>
</div>
```

---

You can also keep the flex direction as row, and change the `flex-basis` to `100%`

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex div {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.flex div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .flex div {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .flex div:nth-child(even) {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>R1<br>R1<br>R1<br>R1<br>R1<br></div>
  <div>B1</div>
  <div>R2</div>
  <div>B2<br>B2<br>B2<br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the height should be respective to the row... (Not a fixed height...)

Comment: I worship you @LGSon. Really. I'm going to make a shrine for you.

Comment: Is it possible to identifiy a 'row' break to add a margin-bottom or something of that sort?

Comment: @Yaron There is no property that can kick in when a row break, for that one use media query and min-width. Can you elaborate a little more how you mean?

Comment: Hi @LGSon I ended up using nth-last-child(4) to add some bottom margin. Only problem now is that the order (Maybe the whole flexbox) not working on Mobile chrome... Any idea how can I fix it? for the flex I added display: -webkit-box; display: -moz-box; display: -ms-flexbox;    display: -moz-flex; display: -webkit-flex; to no avail.

Comment: @Yaron Chrome Mobile shouldn't need prefixed properties, unless it is an old version. If you can make a fiddle with the non working code I'll have a look

Comment: I added -webkit-order: 1; -ms-flex-order: 1; and it now works. Thank you @LGSon !